# Selecting a value and then select this value in the same table and compare in SQL

Tags: sql

```
Customer num.           Value.       Related Customer num 
10001.                  5000.        10002
20001                   3500.        20002
10002.                  4000.        10001
20002.                  3500.        20001
```

I need to find customer nums that the value is not equal to related customer's value.
Please help me.

Comment: Welcome to the site. I recommend that include your CREATE TABLE DDL so that folks can better understand the table structure. Also the answer might have brand specific syntax (possibly) so you should probably tag this question with the brand specific tag of SQL your are using such as SQL Server or MySQL etc.. This will help target your question to the right experts.

Answer (score 0):

Just:

```
select t.*
from mytable t
where not exists (
    select 1 
    from mytable t1 
    where t1.customer_num = t.related_customer_num and t1.value <> t.value
)
```

This ensures that, if a record exists for the related customer, its value is not the same.

If you want also want to check that a record does exists for the related customer:

```
select t.*
from mytable t
inner join mytable t1 
    on  t1.customer_num = t1.related_customer_num 
    and t1.value <> t.value
```

Answer (score 0):

```sql
select
    t1.customerNum
from 
    table t1 
left join 
    table t2 on t1.relatedCustomerNum = t2.customerNum
where 
    t1.value <> t2.value
```

Get all the records and match to related records. You can also add few more filters if needed. For example, `t1 is not null`, which will remove records without related records